# How to Integrate blogging functionality into an HTML template for personal website?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, themes

I've recently bought a HTML5 theme on Envato market and am having a lot of fun playing around with customization as a static file.

What resources can I use to making the blogging functionality work? Jekyll, Rails?

It's a personal design website that I'm making.

Here's the demo website for the theme: https://themeforest.net/item/massive-responsive-multipurpose-html5-template/12503639

Answer (score 1):

You should use Jekyll in combination with CloudCannon. It is really great and free! You can also use Forestry.io.

Note that with CloudCannon you can just upload your HTML with some 'editable' classes on them en get going. Really easy.

Good luck!

Comment: I just checked Cloud Cannon and I think you have to pay for it. It only has a 30-day free trial :(

Comment: What happens after the 30 day trial?

If you haven't added a credit card and selected a plan, you'll be downgraded to our free plan. The free plan restricts access to your sites and removes all the shares you've made.

Comment: You can also try Forestry.io. It is also free: https://forestry.io/plans

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!